# Product of a multi-dimensional array (or tensor) and vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I would like to ask for a fast way to perform the following operations, either in native Matlab, C++, or using toolboxes/libraries, whichever would give the fastest solutions.

Let `M` be a tensor of D dimensions: `n1 x n2 x... x nD`, and let `v1`, `v2`,..., `vD` be `D` vectors whose dimensions are respectively `n1`, `n2`,..., `nD`.

1. Compute the product `M*vi` (1 <= i <= D). The result is a multi-dimensional array of (D-1) dimensions.
2. Compute the product of `M` with all vectors, except `vi`.

For example, with D = 3:

- The product of `M` and `v1` is a tensor `N` of 2 dimensions (i.e. a matrix) where

`N[i2][i3] = Sum_over_i1 of M[i1][i2][i3]*v1[i1]`

- The product of `M` and `v2` is a matrix `N` where

`N[i1][i3] = Sum_over_i2 of M[i1][i2][i3]*v2[i2]`

- The product of `M` and `v2` and `v3` is a vector `v` where

`v[i1] = Sum_over_i2 of (Sum_over_i3 of M[i1][i2][i3]*v2[i2]*v3[i3]`)

A further question: the above but for sparse tensors.

An example of Matlab code is given below.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!

```
n1 = 3;
n2 = 5;
n3 = 4;

M = randn(n1,n2,n3);
v1 = randn(n1,1);
v2 = randn(n2,1);
v3 = randn(n3,1);

%% N = M*v2
N = zeros(n1,n3);
for i1=1:n1
    for i3=1:n3
        for i2=1:n2
            N(i1,i3) = N(i1,i3) + M(i1,i2,i3)*v2(i2);
        end
    end
end

%% v = M*v2*v3
v = zeros(n1,1);
for i1=1:n1
    for i2=1:n2
        for i3=1:n3
            v(i1) = v(i1) + M(i1,i2,i3)*v2(i2)*v3(i3);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: At least the inner for loop you can simplify by using only `N(i1,i3) = M(i1,:,i3)*v2;`

Comment: @RobertStettler: Thanks, but I wanted to write an example that is the most obvious possible. (There might be a way to compute the product of the second type without looping and applying the first one. Otherwise I would not ask for TWO operations but rather for the first one only.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that operation you are describing takes (D - 1) dimensional slices of `M` and scales them by the corresponding entry of `vi` subsequently summing the result over the indices of `vi`. This code seems to work for getting `N` in your example:

```
N2 = squeeze(sum(M.*(v2)', 2));
```

To get `v` in your code, all you need to do is multiply `N` by `v3`:

```
v2 = N2*v3;
```

**EDIT**

On older versions of MatLab the element-wise operator `.*` doesn't work the way I've used it above. One alternative is `bsxfun`:

```
N2 = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, M, v2'), 2));
```

Just checked: In terms of performance, the `bsxfun` way seems as fast as the `.*` way for large arrays, at least on R2016b.

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error when compiling your code: "Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree." Could you please check?

Comment: It could be that we're using different versions of MatLab. In the version I'm using code like this: `ones(2,3).*[1; 2]` or `ones(2, 3).*[1, 2, 3]` works fine, but I remember this not being the case in R2015. To get it to work you might have to use `bsxfun` which might be slower (see Edit).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yuri!